# What's the meaning of "bit-h" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

What's the meaning of *bitch* in the following comment?

> I suggest you stand at the nearest intersection with a cardboard sign, since you're too bitch to get a job and too pussy to rob a bank.

Does the writer mean the person complains a lot about getting a job?

Comment: I think given the fact that the question involves offensive language, you should really be showing much more in-depth research to show good faith. Where did you see this text? What did a dictionary say when you looked up the word? Why do you think the text is grammatical and likely to be of use to learners on ELL in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this [search](http://goo.gl/1NbtK) and from context it either means "unpleasant" or the same as the other epithet in that statement, "weak".

Answer (score 1):

Based on the minimal context and my own personal experience, I'd have to interpret that as basically "severely unpleasant or irritating to deal with; a person who is rude, unpleasant, etc." Essentially, the speaker has left out a few words (a simple case of literary/poetic license, I assume) and converted "bitch" from a noun to an adjective, but kept the same meaning. You should be able to insert "much of a" right in there and keep the same meaning, i.e:

> ...you're too *much of a* bitch to get a job...

Another, equally valid, equally un-modifying, and perhaps more helpful way of paraphrasing would be to simply add a "y" to the end of the word, i.e:

> ...you're too *bitchy* to get a job...

So, long and short, the speaker just means, "No one would ever hire you because you're an utterly unbearable person." That's how I read it, anyway.

Comment: For the context, the person being advised to is basically looking for ways to make a couple thousand dollars in a short period, and he refused to look for a job due to some personal reasons. I have a feeling the B word means *weak* here like Tecbrat suggested, the American [usage](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/bitch).

Comment: I'm an American, native born and bred, and that is by no means the only, nor even the most common, American usage. I can get why you'd think "weak", and you may be right, but I'd say it's at least an uncommon usage of the term, at least in the areas I've lived. It may be more common elsewhere.

Comment: @KenB I am also an American, and I here that word used to mean "weak" or "scared" at least as often as any other usage.

Comment: If you search Google for *"too bitch to"*, you can find similar examples where it probably means something like "too timid, too weak-willed and afraid to do [something]".  I think this example is probably the same thing.  +1, though, for explaining the derivation from noun to adjective.

Comment: @snailboat I usually hear the expression as "*too much of a bitch to...*"